# How to place search boxes side by side in React Js

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am using ReactSearchBox component like below .How do place them vertically side by side and reduce the length of search box too

```
function SearchBarComponent() {
    


    return (
        <div >
            <ReactSearchBox 
                placeholder="Placeholder"
                value="Name"
                data={"A"}
                callback={record => console.log(record)}
                inputBoxHeight="30px"
            />

            <ReactSearchBox 
                placeholder="Placeholder"
                value="Age"
                data={100}
                callback={record => console.log(record)}
                inputBoxHeight="30px"
            />

        </div>
```

I get the Search box as below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OueYR.png)

But i need the search boxes as below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/USPH3.png)

Comment: You could solve that with CSS https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: You can use css `flexbox` to put them side by side and adjust the `width` of parent div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually CSS problem to solve, not React. To simply force them to stay on same line, you could add following styling to the parent div:

```
display: flex;
```

To control each one of the search boxes separately, wrap them in separate divs and style them accordingly with width or any other css properties.

```
<div className="name-input">
  <ReactSearchBox
    placeholder="Placeholder"
    value="Name"
    data={"A"}
    callback={record => console.log(record)}
    inputBoxHeight="30px"
  />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks . your  solution work  but i need some spacing between the 2 search boxes and there should be some space between search boxes and header.Can you tell what property i can use. to implement that

Comment: That's why I provided second code example. You can utilize [margin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin) property to solve this issue

Comment: @benHek margin also works .Just last question I have one more Box  which i want to go to next line.How can i do that

Comment: wrap it into separate div than those 2

Comment: ok ..u mean i need to create a separate JSX element right?i.e a new componment

Comment: you can put it into same one, just add another parent

Comment: can you please show your way please (code snippet). i can solve by creating new component.Your solution seems elegant

Comment: and can u also show how can i space between 2 search boxes.Button should be in next line not in same row as search box